# Releasing instances created with StructureMap in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, structuremap

As a learning exercise I am extending a WCF project so I can use constructor injection on the services using Structure Map. I'm following the example from [this article](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/wcf/Composing-WCF-applications.aspx).

On the IInstanceProvider implementation there is a ReleaseInstance and I am not entirely sure what exactly to do in it.

I am thinking of a situation in which I have service S which has a dependency on class C which has a dependency on repository R. Of course all these dependencies are wired in structure map.

So the basic question is: Do I need to manually do some cleanup in this method or should I just leave everything to structure map?

Thank you for clearing this out.